# Batch script - Quick recursive find of first folder starting from a root location

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a script which finds as quickly as possible first folder named **Target** starting from root location **D:\** and return its absolute path.

***Folder structure of root location (D:\) can be like this:***

-DontSearchHereFolder

-Folder1\Subfolder1\SSubfolder1\SSSubfolder1\

-Folder2\Subfolder2\SSubfolder2\**TargetFolder**

-DontSearchHereFolder2

-Folder3\Subfolder3\

**Output of the script should be:** D:\Folder2\Subfolder2\SSubfolder2\TargetFolder

For now I tried 2 methods but it's not quick enough:

**(1)**

```
set TG=\TargetFolder
set root=D:\
cd %root%

for  /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:d "%root%" ^|findstr /e /i "%TG%"') do set "folderpath=%%~a"
```

**(2)**

```
for /d /r "%root%" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="%TG%" set "folderpath=%%a"
```

***(1) is quicker than (2)***

Question1: Is it possible to specify in command to search only for a maximum of 2 folders "down" from root (**e.g. D:\Folder1\Subfolder1**) ?

Question2: Is it possible to specify folders that should be automatically skipped (**e.g. DontSearchHereFolder1&2**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch code is exactly for what you have asked for optimized for speed. It ignores the two specified directories on first level and it searches for the folders maximal two folder levels deep.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "Root=D:"
set "TG=TargetFolder"
set "Ignore1=DontSearchHereFolder"
set "Ignore2=DontSearchHereFolder2"

for /D %%A in ("%Root%\*") do (
    if "%%~nxA" == "%TG%" set "FolderPath=%%A" & goto Found
    if not "%%~nxA" == "%Ignore1%" (
       if not "%%~nxA" == "%Ignore2%" (
           for /D %%B in ("%%A\*") do (
               if "%%~nxB" == "%TG%" set "FolderPath=%%B" & goto Found
               for /D %%C in ("%%B\*") do if "%%~nxC" == "%TG%" set "FolderPath=%%C" & goto Found
            )
        )
    )
)
echo Could not find folder: "%TG%"
goto EndSearch

:Found
echo Found folder: "%FolderPath%"

:EndSearch
endlocal
```

The string comparisons are done case-sensitive for maximum speed.

No recursive subroutine calls are used as usually would be done for such tasks for maximum speed.

The comparisons for the directories to ignore in root folder are coded in batch script directly not using an array or a list of folder names for maximum speed.

Delayed expansion is not used for faster processing the command lines.

But much faster would be coding an executable in C/C++/C# for that task as processing the command lines of the batch file takes most likely the most time on searching for the folder.

**Note:** Command **FOR** ignores folders with hidden attribute set.

Well, I use for such tasks shareware tool Total Commander which supports searching only in selected folders for a specific folder not more than X levels deep extremely fast.

Comment: Your solution works great! Much faster than what I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should take into account all the limits indicated in the question, but unless a lot of folders are found inside the indicated exclusions, I don't think this should be faster, just give it a try

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=d:\"
    set "target=TargetFolder"
    set "maxLevels=2"
    set excludeFolders= "DontSearchHereFolder" "DontSearchHereFolder2"

    for %%s in ("%source%") do for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('
        robocopy "%%~fs." "%%~fs." /l /nfl /njh /njs /nc /ns /s
            /xd %excludeFolders% /lev:%maxLevels%
        ^| findstr /e /i /l /c:"\\%target%\\"
        ^| cmd /v /q /c"set /p .= &&(echo(!.!)"
    ') do echo "%%~f"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the fastest possible way to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%1" neq "" goto %1

set "root=D:\"
set "TG=TargetFolder"
set "exclude=/DontSearchHereFolder1/DontSearchHereFolder2/"

"%~F0" Input | "%~F0" Output > result.txt
set /P "folderpath=" < result.txt
del result.txt
echo First folder: %folderpath%
goto :EOF


:Input
cd "%root%"
for /D %%a in (*) do if "!exclude:/%%a/=!" equ "%exclude%" (
   cd "%%a"
   dir /B /S /A:D "%TG%" 2>NUL
   cd ..
)
exit /B


:Output
set /P "folder="
echo "%folder%"
set "i=0"
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FO TABLE /NH') do (
   set /A i+=1
   if !i! equ 2 taskkill /PID %%a /F
)
exit /B
```

The folders to exclude are given in a slash-separated list; if this list is longer, the process run faster because more folders are skipped. The target folder is search in each one of the non-excluded folders via a `dir /B /S /AD "%TG%"` command, that is faster than any combination of other commands. The process ends as soon as the first folder name is received in the rigt side of the pipe; the remaining processing at left side of the pipe is cancelled via a `taskkill` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a recursive call of a function

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=140 lines=30
color 3
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


set _FROM_THIS_PATH=<your path from where to begin the search>
set _DIRECTORY_TO_FIND=<your directory name to find>
:: You can skip some directories, maximum number of directories to skip = 6
:: These variables are optionnal, may be not defined
set _DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_1=<1st directory name to skip if needeed>
set _DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_2=<2nd directory name to skip if needeed>
set _DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_3=<etc>
set _DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_4=
set _DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_5=
set _DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_6=
Title Searching for directory (%~nx0)

::##########################################################
:MAIN
::##########################################################

echo.
echo  Searching for "!_DIRECTORY_TO_FIND!" folder from "!_FROM_THIS_PATH!"
echo  -------------------------------------------------

call :SearchForDirectoryPath "!_FROM_THIS_PATH!" "!_DIRECTORY_TO_FIND!" _RETURNED_PATH_OF_DIRECTORY_TO_FIND "!_DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_1!" "!_DIRECTORY_TO_SKIP_2!"

echo.
echo  Path of "!_DIRECTORY_TO_FIND!" : "!_RETURNED_PATH_OF_DIRECTORY_TO_FIND!"
echo.

pause
EndLocal
exit /B

::##########################################################
:SearchForDirectoryPath
::##########################################################

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%N in ('tasklist /FI "imagename eq cmd.exe" /FO list /V ^| find /I "%~Nx0"') do (
    set FN_SCRIPT_NAME=%%N
    set FN_SCRIPT_NAME=!FN_SCRIPT_NAME:~1!
)
set FN_PATH_TO_FIND=

pushd "%~1"
for /D %%D in (*) do call :SearchForDirectoryPath_Process "%%D" "%~2" FN_PATH_TO_FIND "%~4" "%~5" "%~6" "%~7" "%~8" "%~9"
popd

Title !FN_SCRIPT_NAME!
set "%3=!FN_PATH_TO_FIND!"

exit /B

::##########################################################
:SearchForDirectoryPath_Process
::##########################################################

set FN_CURRENT_DIR=%~nx1
set FN_CURRENT_PATH=%~dpnx1
set FN_DIR_TO_FIND=%~2
set FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_1=%~4
set FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_2=%~5
set FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_3=%~6
set FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_4=%~7
set FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_5=%~8
set FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_6=%~9

Title Searching for "!FN_DIR_TO_FIND!" directory : !FN_CURRENT_PATH!

if not defined FN_PATH_TO_FIND2 (
    if !FN_CURRENT_DIR! EQU !FN_DIR_TO_FIND! (
        set "FN_PATH_TO_FIND2=!FN_CURRENT_PATH!"
    ) else (
        if /I [!FN_CURRENT_DIR!] NEQ [!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_1!] (
        if /I [!FN_CURRENT_DIR!] NEQ [!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_2!] (
        if /I [!FN_CURRENT_DIR!] NEQ [!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_3!] (
        if /I [!FN_CURRENT_DIR!] NEQ [!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_4!] (
        if /I [!FN_CURRENT_DIR!] NEQ [!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_5!] (
        if /I [!FN_CURRENT_DIR!] NEQ [!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_6!] (
            pushd "!FN_CURRENT_PATH!"
            for /D %%D in (*) do call :SearchForDirectoryPath_Process "%%D" "!FN_DIR_TO_FIND!" FN_PATH_TO_FIND2 "!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_1!" "!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_2!" "!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_3!" "!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_4!" "!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_5!" "!FN_DIR_TO_SKIP_6!"
            popd
        ))))))
    )
)
set "%3=!FN_PATH_TO_FIND2!"
exit /B
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).